# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string array given

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have an input field in which I am passing an array from my controller as hidden input but its giving me this error of array given.

Code of my view is

```
    <input type="hidden" name="DiseaseDiagnosed[]" value="{{$DiseaseDiagnosed}}">
```

Code of controller passing the value to view is

```
 return view('/doctorPanel/diagnoseDisease', ['chart' => $chart, 'patient' => $patient, 'symptomsStated' => $symptomsStated, 'DiseaseDiagnosed' => $DiseaseDiagnosed]);
```

Kindly tell me why I am getting this error

Answer (score 3):

Blade Template engine is producing this error. you can't print array like this using `{{ }}`. When passing this value, you can encode it using `'DiseaseDiagnosed'=>json_encode($DiseaseDiagnosed])`, then you can use that syntax. After that when you want to use this value, don't forget to decode it using `json_decode()`

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="hidden" name="DiseaseDiagnosed[]" value="{!! jsond_encode($DiseaseDiagnosed) !!}">
```

Actually, your input is `DiseaseDiagnosed` is an array which is returned to view.

So you have to use `{{ json_decode($DiseaseDiagnosed) }}`

You can also try

```
@foreach($DiseaseDiagnosed as $disease)

  <input type="hidden" name="DiseaseDiagnosed[]" value="{{ $disease }}">

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to create an array with inputs you need to have **1 input** for e**ach value** inside the array. You are appending an array on the value when it only accepts Strings so thats why it warns you that an array was given when a String was expected.

As @Adnan suggested you can solve this using:

```
@foreach($DiseaseDiagnosed as $disease)

   <input type="hidden" name="DiseaseDiagnosed[]" value="{{ $disease }}">

@endforeach
```

Then in your controller you will recieve the array DiseaseDiagnosed with all the values you inserted, eg: *You will recieve all the values within the same array->*

```
dd($request->DiseaseDiagnosed);
// You will see this is an array with all the values
```